# MongoDB/NoSQL: Keeping Document Change History

Tags: mongodb, nosql

A fairly common requirement in database applications is to track changes to one or more specific entities in a database.  I've heard this called row versioning, a log table or a history table (I'm sure there are other names for it).  There are a number of ways to approach it in an RDBMS--you can write all changes from all source tables to a single table (more of a log) or have a separate history table for each source table.  You also have the option to either manage the logging in application code or via database triggers.

I'm trying to think through what a solution to the same problem would look like in a NoSQL/document database (specifically MongoDB), and how it would be solved in a uniform way.  Would it be as simple as creating version numbers for documents, and never overwriting them?  Creating separate collections for "real" vs. "logged" documents?  How would this affect querying and performance?

Anyway, is this a common scenario with NoSQL databases, and if so, is there a common solution?

Comment: What language driver are you using?

Comment: Not decided yet--still tinkering and have not even finalized the choice of back ends yet (although MongoDB looks *extrememly* likely).  I have been tinkering with NoRM (C#), and I like some of the names associated with that project, so it seems very likely to be the choice.

Comment: I know this is a old question but for anyone who is looking for versioning with MongoDB, this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185105/ways-to-implement-data-versioning-in-mongodb) is related and in my opionion with better answers.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Good question, I was looking into this myself as well.

#### Create a new version on each change

I came across the [Versioning module](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html) of the Mongoid driver for Ruby. I haven't used it myself, but from [what I could find](http://neovintage.blogspot.com/2010/06/mongoid-versioning-run-down.html), it adds a version number to each document. Older versions are embedded in the document itself. The major drawback is that the **entire document is duplicated on each change**, which will result in a lot of duplicate content being stored when you're dealing with large documents. This approach is fine though when you're dealing with small-sized documents and/or don't update documents very often.

#### Only store changes in a new version

Another approach would be to **store only the changed fields in a new version**. Then you can 'flatten' your history to reconstruct any version of the document. This is rather complex though, as you need to track changes in your model and store updates and deletes in a way that your application can reconstruct the up-to-date document. This might be tricky, as you're dealing with structured documents rather than flat SQL tables.

#### Store changes within the document

Each field can also have an individual history. Reconstructing documents to a given version is much easier this way. In your application you don't have to explicitly track changes, but just create a new version of the property when you change its value. A document could look something like this:

```
{
  _id: "4c6b9456f61f000000007ba6"
  title: [
    { version: 1, value: "Hello world" },
    { version: 6, value: "Foo" }
  ],
  body: [
    { version: 1, value: "Is this thing on?" },
    { version: 2, value: "What should I write?" },
    { version: 6, value: "This is the new body" }
  ],
  tags: [
    { version: 1, value: [ "test", "trivial" ] },
    { version: 6, value: [ "foo", "test" ] }
  ],
  comments: [
    {
      author: "joe", // Unversioned field
      body: [
        { version: 3, value: "Something cool" }
      ]
    },
    {
      author: "xxx",
      body: [
        { version: 4, value: "Spam" },
        { version: 5, deleted: true }
      ]
    },
    {
      author: "jim",
      body: [
        { version: 7, value: "Not bad" },
        { version: 8, value: "Not bad at all" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Marking part of the document as deleted in a version is still somewhat awkward though. You could introduce a `state` field for parts that can be deleted/restored from your application:

```
{
  author: "xxx",
  body: [
    { version: 4, value: "Spam" }
  ],
  state: [
    { version: 4, deleted: false },
    { version: 5, deleted: true }
  ]
}
```

With each of these approaches you can store an up-to-date and flattened version in one collection and the history data in a separate collection. This should improve query times if you're only interested in the latest version of a document. But when you need both the latest version and historical data, you'll need to perform two queries, rather than one. So the choice of using a single collection vs. two separate collections should depend on **how often your application needs the historical versions**.

Most of this answer is just a brain dump of my thoughts, I haven't actually tried any of this yet. Looking back on it, the first option is probably the easiest and best solution, unless the overhead of duplicate data is very significant for your application. The second option is quite complex and probably isn't worth the effort. The third option is basically an optimization of option two and should be easier to implement, but probably isn't worth the implementation effort unless you really can't go with option one.

Looking forward to feedback on this, and other people's solutions to the problem :)

Comment: What about storing deltas somewhere, so that you have to flatten to get a historical document and always have the current available?

Comment: @jpmc26 That's similar to the second approach, but instead of saving the deltas to get to the latest versions, you're saving deltas to get to the historical versions. Which approach to use depends on how often you'll need the historical versions.

Comment: You could add an paragraph about using the document as a view into the current state of things and having a second document as a changelog that will track each change including a timestamp (initial values need to appear in this log) - you can then 'replay' to any given point in time and e.g. correlate what was going on when your algorithm touched it or see how an item was displayed when the user clicked on it.

Comment: Will this affect performance if indexed fields represented as arrays?

Comment: @All - Could you please share some code to achieve this ?

Comment: This might sound absurd. Could you do the method1 but with a single document?. Bascially the document would have one main entity which is an array of past and current documents. If the original document has like 5~10 entities only and can have up to 3~5 histories. It would be equivalent of max 50 entities in a single document

Comment: @SihoonKim, as I mentioned in the answer, "_Older versions are embedded in the document itself._" So I don't fully understand your question. Do you mean storing multiple entities (e.g. users or products) in a single document? Of course you could do that, but I don't see the benefits of that over having one document per entity, with its history included in the document.

Comment: Oh never mind, I thought the first one was just making new documents on every update. So i guess, this method is not absurd.

Comment: What if the second history tracking collection had a document in it for each document. The history tracking document would be a document that had keys for each revision. The first rev ('rev': 0) would be a JSON string of the document and each rev after that would be a diff entry of new version versus the previous version. Then you apply patches to the original successively until you get to the version you are interested in. Each rev entry can also have a datetime stamp if desired.

Answer (score 18):

Why not a variation on **Store changes within the document** ?

Instead of storing versions against each key pair, the current key pairs in the document always represents the most recent state and a 'log' of changes is stored within a history array. Only those keys which have changed since creation will have an entry in the log.

```
{
  _id: "4c6b9456f61f000000007ba6"
  title: "Bar",
  body: "Is this thing on?",
  tags: [ "test", "trivial" ],
  comments: [
    { key: 1, author: "joe", body: "Something cool" },
    { key: 2, author: "xxx", body: "Spam", deleted: true },
    { key: 3, author: "jim", body: "Not bad at all" }
  ],
  history: [
    { 
      who: "joe",
      when: 20160101,
      what: { title: "Foo", body: "What should I write?" }
    },
    { 
      who: "jim",
      when: 20160105,
      what: { tags: ["test", "test2"], comments: { key: 3, body: "Not baaad at all" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to store the document in the new collection rather than storing inside it? Everytime we query the document, it will come along and large number of changes will increase the data size.

Comment: @kirtan403 Mongo queries have projections, only the things you project will be returned, so you decide yourself which parts of the document come along.

Comment: The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes..

Answer (score 10):

We have partially implemented this on our site and we use the 'Store Revisions in a separate document" (and separate database).  We wrote a custom function to return the diffs and we store that.  Not so hard and can allow for automated recovery.

Comment: Could you please share some code around the same ? This approach look promising

Comment: @smilyface - Spring Boot Javers integration is best to achieve this

Comment: @PAA - I have asked a question (almost same concept). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56683389/compare-two-pojo-and-output-difference-to-another-pojo?noredirect=1#comment99933014_56683389 Do you have any input for that ?

Answer (score 5):

One can have a current NoSQL database and a historical NoSQL database. There will be a an nightly ETL ran everyday. This ETL will record every value with a timestamp, so instead of values it will always be tuples (versioned fields). It will only record a new value if there was a change made on the current value, saving space in the process. For example, this historical NoSQL database json file can look like so:

```
{
  _id: "4c6b9456f61f000000007ba6"
  title: [
    { date: 20160101, value: "Hello world" },
    { date: 20160202, value: "Foo" }
  ],
  body: [
    { date: 20160101, value: "Is this thing on?" },
    { date: 20160102, value: "What should I write?" },
    { date: 20160202, value: "This is the new body" }
  ],
  tags: [
    { date: 20160101, value: [ "test", "trivial" ] },
    { date: 20160102, value: [ "foo", "test" ] }
  ],
  comments: [
    {
      author: "joe", // Unversioned field
      body: [
        { date: 20160301, value: "Something cool" }
      ]
    },
    {
      author: "xxx",
      body: [
        { date: 20160101, value: "Spam" },
        { date: 20160102, deleted: true }
      ]
    },
    {
      author: "jim",
      body: [
        { date: 20160101, value: "Not bad" },
        { date: 20160102, value: "Not bad at all" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For users of Python (python 3+, and up of course) , there's [HistoricalCollection](https://pypi.org/project/historical-collection/) that's an extension of pymongo's Collection object.

Example from the docs:

```
from historical_collection.historical import HistoricalCollection
from pymongo import MongoClient
class Users(HistoricalCollection):
    PK_FIELDS = ['username', ]  # <<= This is the only requirement

# ...

users = Users(database=db)

users.patch_one({"username": "darth_later", "email": "darthlater@example.com"})
users.patch_one({"username": "darth_later", "email": "darthlater@example.com", "laser_sword_color": "red"})

list(users.revisions({"username": "darth_later"}))

# [{'_id': ObjectId('5d98c3385d8edadaf0bb845b'),
#   'username': 'darth_later',
#   'email': 'darthlater@example.com',
#   '_revision_metadata': None},
#  {'_id': ObjectId('5d98c3385d8edadaf0bb845b'),
#   'username': 'darth_later',
#   'email': 'darthlater@example.com',
#   '_revision_metadata': None,
#   'laser_sword_color': 'red'}]
```

Full disclosure, I am the package author. :)