# Track record/document changes?

Tags: meteor

It doesn't appear to be built-in to Meteor but is there an accepted way to track changes to a record/document?   I can think of a number of ways to do this but am curious how others have accomplished this.

An example would be someone's location, if you wanted to track changes for a set period of time.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the canonical `Collection.find(query).observeChanges()` not do that you want it to do? See http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes

Comment: So what if you wanted to see last 5 changes, for example.  Would you observeChanges(), then add changes to another object, perhaps MyObject_history or similar.  This probably my relational database mindset but curious what the ideal Meteor way would be.

Comment: So are you trying to track revisions to a document? If so, I don't think this is a meteor question; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507624/mongodb-nosql-keeping-document-change-history and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185105/ways-to-implement-data-versioning-in-mongodb

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  Nice to know there wasn't something already in Meteor that I was missing.  In my case, I'll make a new 'changes' document for each document and give it the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this package yet but it seems to track revisions and give the ability to restore older versions. I'm going to test it out now.

https://github.com/todda00/meteor-collection-revisions

**Update:** I can confirm that this package works in Meteor 1.3. It makes a complete copy of the document of the edited Meteor collection and stores it as an array within the document under "revisions". You can then restore any previous version using the `revisionId` later on.

Comment: Note that todda00's repo of meteor-collection-revisions is no longer maintained. Try the following fork instead:
https://github.com/nicklozon/meteor-collection-revisions Overall, it seems like a good implementation and reasonably stable by now.