# Does Mongo db have a built in feature to auto increment document versions

Tags: mongodb, document-versioning

Does Mongo DB has any built-in feature to auto increment versions of a document. If the newly inserted document is different then to create a new version and save previous as history.
I have referred to the MongoDB Document Versioning Pattern blog, want to know if there is this feature built in?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3507624/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , For Mongodb-Java is there any similar library like  Mongoose versioned https://github.com/pier4all/mongoose-versioned which is available for mongodb-nodejs or like Historical-collection https://pypi.org/project/historical-collection/    for python